# Django how to create different view

Tags: django

I write some createview in my views.py file just like UserCreateView,DeptCreateView.

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):

    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'add.html'
    success_url = '/member/'

    def get_initial(self):
        return { 'date': datetime.date.today }

class DeptCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Dept
    form_class = DeptForm
    template_name = 'add.html'
    success_url = '/member/'
```

I want to add a MyCreateView to choose which UserCreateView or DeptCreateView to add.

```
def MyCreateView(request):
    table = request.POST['table']
    create = { 'User': UserCreateView,
            'Dept': DeptCreateView,
            }
    p = create[str(table)].as_view()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(p))
```

I get a error message

> Reverse for 'oa.views.UserCreateView' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The error message indicates that something is wrong with your url. Did you add the mentioned url to you url.py? And does the name match with the Reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the way to do it at all. There's no point in using the view classes in your dispatch dictionary.

Instead, give each URL pattern a name, and use that in your reverse call:

```
url(r'/url/for/user_create', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='user_create')
url(r'/url/for/dept_create', DeptCreateView.as_view(), name='dept_create')
```

...

```
create = { 'User': 'user_create',
           'Dept': 'dept_create',
         }
p = create[table]
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(p))
```

Comment: You could also have one view which dispatches via other views, [as in the mixin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#an-alternative-better-solution) (in a slightly different situation).

Comment: Thank you very much,the error have already confuse me a long time.